# In Lucene.NET, how to reuse the indexed data that is created using SOLR.NET

Tags: c#-4.0, solr, lucene.net, solr.net

I have a written a sample project in which i have created an index using **SOLR.NET (.NET Wrapper Java Based SOLR)**

I want to remove the dependency of Java. So i am trying **Lucene.NET**.

Now is it possible to **re-use** the same indexed data (Created with SOLR.NET & SOLR) and perform searches / updates to that index data using **LUCENE.NET**?

Environment: VS2013, C#, .NET Framework 4.0, WinForms

Answer (score 0):

The Lucene codec format evolves over time, and most alternative Lucene implementation are only compatible with a specific range of versions. So the answer is "it depends, but probably not". You'd have to try to read the segment files present in your Solr installation with Lucene.NET instead.

Remember that this moves Solr from being a distributed dependency (running as a separate server) to an in-process dependency instead - requiring you to write your own service on top of Lucene.NET if you want to keep it distributed.

As you've just written a sample project, drop everything you've indexed and re-index with your own code for Lucene.NET instead.